# How to implement Right Click Option In ASP.NET Treeview

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview showing Categories and subcategories.
I need to Right Click Option to add subcategories and products for a particular category or subcategory.

What I want is suppose I have selected a treenode showing a category or subcategory. When I right click on a treenode it will show a contextmenu having options -- Add subcategory, Add product, Delete this category, Edit this category. When I click on one of the menu item it will open a popup to add/Edit/Delete Category or add product.

I hope you can understand my problem. please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty complicated, so if you're not sure what you're doing you'd be better off googling for a 3rd party component that already does right-click.

e.g.

http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/treeview/features/node_contextMenus/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: Do I have to buy the componentart web UI?

Comment: linkrot : http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/treeview/features/node_contextMenus/WebForm1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution FlyTreeView for ASP.NET (versions 2.0, 3.0, 3.5) in this
[Link](http://www.9rays.net/Products/TreeView_ASP.NET_2/)

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin [jContext](http://www.gimiti.com/kltan/wordpress/?p=23). You might have to do a couple extra things when working with ASP.NET webforms.

You will have to study the html that gets generated by the treeview control.

For example, web forms controls render html elements with an ID attribute that can vary on many factors. So, your javascript code will have to reference these elements in a different way than usual:

```
$('#<%=someControl.ClientID %>').whatever();
```